# What instruments are wind instruments for purposes of being a Windsinger?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, bard, objects, music

In the game I am running, there are several characters who are bards with the Windsinger feat (Stormwrack p94).  The players and I have been debating what qualifies as a wind instrument for purposes of using them to activate this feat, as this feat specifies:

> You can use song or a wind instrument to compel the winds to obey you.

This is a somewhat high-tech black-powder age-of-sail campaign, and there are more instruments available than are specified in the Players Handbook p79.

In particular, we were debating [squeezeboxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeezebox) such as the accordion or concertina, and [bagpipes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bagpipes).  All of these instruments rely upon air pressure to function, and are [aerophones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerophone), but the squeezeboxes are played by using muscular effort to provide air pressure rather than blowing into the instrument and the squeezeboxes have keys or holes.

What instruments available circa 1800s real-world Earth would be considered suitable for purposes of activating the Windsinger feat, and why?

Answer (score 6):

### There is just not much to go by

The game doesn’t define “wind instrument,” it’s just up to the table/DM. As [Peregrin’s great answer details](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/209503/4563), *Stormwrack* does use “wind instrument” elsewhere, in a way that *might* be a definition, so you could go with that. However, it’s not “the official” rule because that definition—if it is one—is part of a specific rule that may or may not apply to Windsinger, a completely separate specific rule. (In other words, it’s not a given that the authors are using “wind instrument” as a consistent term with a strict definition in the first place.)

The real-world definition of “wind instrument” isn’t any better, without much in the way of hard-and-fast definitions,¹ and even if there was, it’s exceedingly unlikely that the author knew it and intended it.

At the end of the day, there just isn't an official answer. Choose whatever is best for your campaign. The feat is not very strong, and the requirement is about flavor, not balance (singing is already the “best” instrument, mechanically, since it doesn’t require any hands). That would have me inclined to allow it with whatever, but ultimately the decision rests with your table/DM.

1. <sub>[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wind_instrument) says it has to be played by breathing into it; [Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/art/wind-instrument) says it can be anything where vibrating air makes the sound, and explicitly discuss examples that don’t involve breath, including the pipe organ mentioned in Peregrin’s answer. For what it’s worth, the Wikipedia article has a “multiple issues” quality warning, though, and the Britannica article reads as better researched from my skimming.</sub>

Comment: Not very strong?!  It can mean the difference between advantage and disadvantage in ship to ship combat!  Still +1 from me.

Comment: @MontyWild Far, far more powerful wind control is available, and ship-to-ship combat is almost never used. In a near-exclusively naval game played extensively at very-low levels, I could see taking it, but it’s not exactly a must-have even in that scenario.

Comment: More powerful, yes, but not longer *duration*.  The limit of Wind Singer is the ability of the bard to continue to perform.  Other spells before Control Weather becomes available have a pathetic duration.

Comment: @MontyWild I’ll confess that I am not familiar with the durations of all the various wind-control spells and other features out there, so you may be right about that. It’s never come up for me; we always do “ship” combat as boarding actions played using the normal combat rules and whatever environmental/circumstantial effects are appropriate. No one at my table has ever really cared to worry about ship maneuvering or whatever. Then again, we don’t have cannons.

Comment: It's a shame about the feat's prerequisite. *DMG* demographics make level 2 and higher bards pretty rare. Still, I can imagine the feat (*ahem*) turning the tide if the DM rules that the bards are each the source of the effect—rather than the feat being the source of the effect—therefore letting those effects stack. So 4 Brd2s taking a standard action to turn a moderate wind into a hurricane facing any direction? That's a plot. ("Why were they hiding a ship in the barn?")

Comment: @HeyICanChan Ah, yeah, I would not allow stacking like that, but that certainly would raise my estimation of its value.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Wind Singer doesn't work that way.  It allows the crew to use the Profession(Sailing) DCs as if the wind was 1 step lighter, and allows shifting the source of the wind by ±45° *for the ship the windsinger is on*.  Going by general D&D rules, things don't stack unless the rules specifically say so.

Comment: @MontyWild My notes have *Stormwrack*'s Table 1–2 pasted nearby, and that fooled me into assuming that the feat was, like, good, but you're right in that it only reduces the danger to the ship of high winds. Still, a separate paragraph does say, "You can also alter the direction of the wind by one compass point," and that *is* significant thing. (And, yes, I agree that it's usually a bad idea for the DM to rule that the character rather than the game element is a source for stacking effects, but a DM *can* rule that way since the rules are unclear.)

Answer (score 6):

On page 48 of the Stormwrack rulebook  in the section about bardic music it reads:

> wind instruments, pipes, accordions, bagpipes, and similar instruments
> do not function underwater.

There are two ways to understand this:

1. *wind instruments ***and*** pipes ***and*** accordions ***and*** bagpipes, and similar instruments do not function underwater*

or

2. wind instruments, ***like*** pipes, accordions, bagpipes, and similar instruments do not function underwater.

Since pipes definitely belong to wind instruments, version 1 would not make sense. That's why I think pipes, accordions, bagpipes are given as examples for the category "wind instruments".

Comment: Neither would pipe organs, but they're specifically keyboard instruments, so I don't think that it follows that all those instruments are wind instruments.

Comment: @MontyWild The Britannica entry I linked specifically includes pipe organs as an example of a wind instrument, so I don’t think the “wind instrument” and “keyboard instrument” categories are necessarily mutually exclusive.

Comment: Anyway, +1 for an actual sourced statement within _Stormwrack_, I was quite certain such a thing didn’t exist. It’s got a bit of ambiguity (as you’ve shown) and a bit of the usual “is the definition used in this specific rule applicable to some other specific rule?” but it’s far more useful than I thought the book was.

Comment: If the author meant the second meaning, he would use a colon instead of a comma: "Wind instruments:  pipes, accordions, bagpipes, and similar instruments do not function underwater.".

Comment: @TrangOul Pfffft, no. Wizards of the Coast’s authors were never **remotely** that careful with their punctuation. Expecting the text to be written that carefully will only result in deceiving yourself.